# How to debug and fix the error in the Django

Tags: django

One of the most important problems we face in Django is how to fix the error. There is an error below that I do not know how to troubleshoot and fix the error.
What is the best approach and tools for error detection?

```
E:\Bourse\BourseWebApp\BourseDjangoAPI>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Bourse\BourseWebApp\BourseDjangoAPI\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Bourse\BourseWebApp\BourseDjangoAPI\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 638, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 623, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 329, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 335, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 375, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 391, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 289, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 116, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 152, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1407, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\Maryam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1221, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Can those who are familiar or master with Django, advise how to fix the problem in case of a error?
Thanks

Comment: the error message is pretty clear - you have no "django rest framework" installed. The best approach is to create and activate a virtualenv and execute "pip install djangorestframework"

Comment: How to detect the error is beacause of lack of rest_frameork? In my virtual environment, I run pip install rest_framework, the message is shown: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rest_framework (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rest_framework
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'e:\bourse\boursewebapp\benv\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

Comment: try "pip install djangorestframework"  instead of "pip install rest_framework" as it described here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation

Comment: When I run the "pip list --local" command, the djangorestframework package is listed.

Comment: and have 'rest_framework' in INSTALLED_APPS  in settings.py ?

Comment: Yes, I added 'rest_framework' in the INSTALLED_APPS section in file settings.py before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237454/discussion-between-arpa-and-maryam).